# Integrals of functions with poles on the real axis (Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem) in the sense of Distributions/Generalized Functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, distribution-theory, quantum-field-theory

The Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem [[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem)] states that
$$ 
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0 } \int_{\mathbb R} dz \; \frac{f(z)}{z \pm i \epsilon} = \mp i \pi f(0) + \mathcal{P} \int dz \; \frac{f(z)}{z} \;, 
 $$
for $f$ analytic on $\mathbb C$.
This is often expressed in physics literature as
$$
\frac{1}{z \pm i \epsilon} = \mp i \pi \delta(x) + \mathcal{P}\frac{1}{x} \;,
$$
which makes heuristic sense. Is this rigorously valid in the sense of distributions, i.e given any test function $\varphi \in \mathcal{C}_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ (smooth and compactly supported), can we show that
$$
\int_{C^\pm} dx \; \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} = \mp i \pi \varphi(0) + \mathcal{P} \int dx \; \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} \;,
$$
where $C^\pm$ is the real line indented around the origin into the upper and lower half planes respectively, and suitably closed at infinity. In attempting to mimic the proof for analytic functions, I fail to make sense of the right hand side contour integral - how to have suitable test functions on the complex plane that are analytic (so that we can use Cauchy's theorem), as anlaytic functions that vanish on a segment of real axis will necessarily vanish everywhere.